# Paying for a forbidden service

Tags: choshen-mishpat-civil-law, sin, employment, sorcery-magic-kishuf

If one hires someone to do a service that is halachically forbidden, is he obligated/allowed to pay for it, e.g. [blei gissen](http://www.aish.com/sp/so/The-Evil-Eye-Remover.html).

Answer (score 3):

Tosfos ([Bava Kama 71a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=21&daf=71&format=pdf), sv אילו [starts the page before]) writes

> כיון שצריך לתת לה לצאת ידי שמים...חשיב אתנן ולא מתנה
>
> Since he has to give it to her, in order to fulfil his Heavenly
>   obligation...it is considered to be an "אתנן" (and therefore forbidden
>   as a *korban*), and not a gift.

So payment for prostitution (a forbidden service, by all accounts) cannot be enforced by an earthly court, but is still obligatory לצאת ידי שמים.

---

*h/t [Fred](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1442/fred) for [helping me](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53687/paying-for-a-forbidden-service?noredirect=1#comment142688_53687) find the Tosfos. Thanks!*